# WordPress redirect matched string in URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to do a 301 redirect using .htaccess file to redirect:

Target URL:
`https://blanee.com/punaises-de-lit/punaises-de-lit-peau-de-mue/bpage/2000/`

and after Redirection the URL :
`https://blanee.com/punaises-de-lit/punaises-de-lit-peau-de-mue`

I want to remove `/bpage/2000/` that string from the URL.

NOTE: `/2000/` this is an integer number, 1-2000 or more than more numbers in the URL, this random number, That I want to fetch.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/bpage/([a-zA-Z])$
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /knowledgebase/ [L,R=301]
 
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have that code already uses in my WordPress

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^(punaises-de-lit/punaises-de-lit-peau-de-mue)/bpage/\d+/?$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Put this at the top of your htaccess just below the line that says `RewriteEngine on` .

Comment: But. There is more url like (punaises-de-lit/punaises-de-lit-peau-de-mue) .
I need to redirect those all link.
I have 200+ URLs like this

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z])/bpage/\d+/?$ /$1 [L,R=301] `

I have uses it, But nothing happened

Comment: @fxcjahid Since your path also contain `-` , you will need to use this pattern `^([a-zA-Z-_]+)` . 301 Redirects are always cached by web browser , so clear your browser cache before you   test this new pattern .

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/bpage/\d+/?$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is worked for me.
Put this at the top of your ***.htaccess*** just below the line that says `RewriteEngine on` .